# Mac OSX 12.4 (Monterey). Trying to compile an old Python code. Configure: error: set PETSC_DIR to point at PETSc installation. Related to gfortran?

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, mpi, configure, petsc

I have been trying to compile an old Python code.  A couple of days ago I posted a question that described problems with accessing Python and gfortran.  I solved the Python problem, then the question no longer made sense.  It had no answers so I deleted it.  However, now when I run a "configure" script, I'm getting an error that I don't understand:

```
configure: error: You need to set PETSC_DIR to point at your PETSc installation... exiting
```

An online search to find out what PETSc is turned up a forum post (https://github.com/firedrakeproject/firedrake/issues/1703) that mentions "gfortran" and I wonder that's where my problem is.  I installed gcc via Homebrew to get gfortran and now see it at `/usr/local/bin/gfortran`.  In my `.zshrc` file, I added:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
alias python=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

When I do:

```
gfortran --version
```

I get (which seems fine):

```
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_2) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I do:

```
which gfortran
```

I get the following.

```
aliased to gfortran -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
```

The other thing that seems relevant is that I just did:

```
brew install openmpi
```

to overcome an error related to not having MPI.  I don't know anything about using MPI on a Mac so it's likely this is where I'm going wrong.

```
configure: error: no MPI support found on system
```

Here are the clues from the "configure" script log file:

```
checking for malloc in -ltcmalloc... no
configure: WARNING: No tcmalloc support available.
checking for mpif90... no
checking for mpf90... no
checking for mpicc... no
checking for mpcc... no
checking for mpicxx... no
checking for mpiCC... no
checking for mpCC... no
checking if we can compile and link without using -lmpi... no
checking if we can compile and link using -lmpi... no
checking if we can compile and link using mpich libs... no
configure: error: no MPI support found on system
```

I would be very grateful if someone could please point me in the right direction.

Comment: you likely did not correctly install `openmpi`. What do `mpirun -V` and `type mpif90` report?

Comment: That Firedrake post is likely a dead-end unless your python code uses Firedrake. Petsc is a widely used numerical library. Does your code have documentation on how it uses petsc? Does it try to `pip` install petsc (or something like that) or does it assume that you have installed petsc?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, sorry for the late reply.  Spotty internet access right now.  "mpirun -V" give me "mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.4."  "type mpif90" gives me "mpif90 is /usr/local/bin/mpif90."

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, no there's no documentation, unfortunately and I don't see a "pip install petsc."  I searched online and couldn't find it, but will have a more thorough look when I have internet again later today.  Thank you very much.

Comment: try looking into `config.log` to understand why `checking for mpif90... no`. Per your comment, this does not make any sense to me yet.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, it does have "configure:10939: checking for mpif90" with "configure:10960: found /usr/local/bin/mpif90." It also has "configure:11039: checking for mpicc" and "configure:11087: checking for mpicxx" with "configure:11060: found /usr/local/bin/mpicc" and "configure:11108: found /usr/local/bin/mpicxx."  Finally, it has this: "configure:11137: checking if we can compile and link without using -lmpi" with "configure:11163: mpicc -o conftest ."  Not sure what that last one means.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, I figured out how to install petsc. Thank you for the hint!  The errors have disappeared, although I need to figure out if any warnings are a problem.  I have a new error, "configure: error: "Could not link with Zoltan library.""  So I'll look for Zoltan library now.  If you want to add an answer, I can choose it.  Thank you very much, everyone for your advice.

Comment: Zoltan is (I think) a graph partitioner, and it can be part of petsc as an optional installation, so maybe your code assumes that you have a petsc with zoltan included.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, that makes a lot of sense.  In this code, I think Zoltan and petsc are related to meshing.  It looks like it'll be difficult to figure out how to get a mesh code I'm familiar with to work with this code, so that's why I'm slogging through this installation instead of just using the parts of the code I need to write my own code!  I do hope you'll add an answer so you can get credit!  Thank you!

Comment: Not related to my original question so maybe it's pushing it to post it, but the outstanding problem is linking with the Zoltan library.  Can't find documentation on that and can't tell whether the linking should happen in the configure script for the old code I'm trying to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message indicates that the PETSc library is missing. You can probably find a `pip` installation that gives you petsc with a python interface.

However, your further problem with Zoltan indicates that (probably) you need a petsc installation that has zoltan as optional package. I'm not sure that you can find a `pip` install for that. You may need to install petsc entirely by hand.

https://petsc.org/release/install/

and use the configuration options `--with-zoltan --with-mpi4py`.